# SQL Select related tables into new columns

Tags: oracle

I have a table in SQL that has 3 columns:

- CategoryName
- WarnInterval
- ErrorInterval

And then I have another table which has 4 columns:

- CategoryName
- GroupName
- IncludedExcluded
- Match

Each row in this table has 2 unique records based on CategoryName, GroupName and IncludedExcluded. For example, as json it looks like this:

```
{
    categoryName: 'Folders',
    groupName: 'Products',
    includeExcluded: 'E',
    match: 'SomeProduct'
}, {
    categoryName: 'Folders',
    groupName: 'Products',
    includeExcluded: 'I',
    match: 'SomeOtherProduct'
}
```

There are 3 Groups (Products, Reps and BusinessCategories), so each Category has only 6 rows of data in this table.
I want to generate an SQL statement that pulls the tables into columns that I can then parse into a json object like this:

```
{
    categoryName: 'Folders',
    warnInterval: 40,
    errorInterval: 60,
    groups: [{
        groupName: 'Products',
        Include: 'SomeProduct',
        Exclude: 'SomeOtherProduct' 
    }, {
        groupName: 'Reps',
        Include: 'SomeRep',
        Exclude: 'SomeOtherRep' 
    }, {
        groupName: 'BusinessCategories',
        Include: 'SomeCategory',
        Exclude: 'SomeOtherCategory' 
    }]
}
```

I would like the SQL statement to join the 2 tables and present the data into columns like this:

- CategoryName
- WarnInterval
- ErrorInterval
- ProductTitle (this is the group name)
- ProductIncludes (If the IncludedExcluded value is 'I' then put the match in this column)
- ProductExcludes (If the IncludedExcluded value is 'E' then put the match in this column)
- RepresentativeTitle
- RepresentativeIncludes
- RepresentativeExcludes
- BusinessCategoryTitle
- BusinessCategoryIncludes
- BusinessCategoryExcludes

I really hope I explained that well. Can someone help me with the SQL for this? PS, it is Oracle :)

Comment: Can you share your table creation scripts so I can build some example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after.  The query really breaks the category_matches table into a set of six datasets - three groups * two include / exclude flags.

The list of columns in your question includes "ProductTitle (this is the group name)" which doesn't make sense since each of the groups is represented in each row of data.  But maybe I have misunderstood

```
WITH
 category_intervals (category_name, warn_interval, error_interval) AS 
 (SELECT 'Folders',40,60 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catA',10,20 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catB',50,100 FROM dual 
 )
,category_matches(category_name, group_name, include_exclude, match_name) AS
 (SELECT 'Folders','Products','E','Product 1' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Folders','Products','I','Product 2' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Folders','Reps','E','Rep 1' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Folders','Reps','I','Rep 2' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Folders','Business Categories','E','Category 1' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Folders','Business Categories','I','Category 2' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  --
  SELECT 'catA','Products','E','Product 3' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catA','Products','I','Product 4' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'catA','Reps','E','Rep 3' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catA','Reps','I','Rep 4' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'catA','Business Categories','E','Category 3' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catA','Business Categories','I','Category 4' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  --
  SELECT 'catB','Products','E','Product 5' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catB','Products','I','Product 6' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'catB','Reps','E','Rep 5' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catB','Reps','I','Rep 6' FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'catB','Business Categories','E','Category 5' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'catB','Business Categories','I','Category 6' FROM dual 
 )
SELECT
 ci.category_name
,ci.warn_interval
,ci.error_interval
,ip.match_name           product_include
,ep.match_name           product_exclude
,ir.match_name           rep_include
,er.match_name           rep_exclude
,ibc.match_name          bus_cat_include
,ibc.match_name          bus_catt_exclude
FROM
 category_intervals   ci
,(SELECT *
  FROM category_matches  
  WHERE group_name = 'Products'
  AND include_exclude = 'I'
 ) ip 
,(SELECT *
  FROM category_matches  
  WHERE group_name = 'Products'
  AND include_exclude = 'E'
 ) ep 
,(SELECT *
  FROM category_matches  
  WHERE group_name = 'Reps'
  AND include_exclude = 'I'
 ) ir 
,(SELECT *
  FROM category_matches  
  WHERE group_name = 'Reps'
  AND include_exclude = 'E'
 ) er
,(SELECT *
  FROM category_matches  
  WHERE group_name = 'Business Categories'
  AND include_exclude = 'I'
 ) ibc 
,(SELECT *
  FROM category_matches  
  WHERE group_name = 'Business Categories'
  AND include_exclude = 'E'
 ) ebc 
WHERE 1=1
AND ci.category_name = ip.category_name
AND ci.category_name = ep.category_name
AND ci.category_name = ir.category_name
AND ci.category_name = er.category_name
AND ci.category_name = ibc.category_name
AND ci.category_name = ebc.category_name
ORDER BY
 ci.category_name
;
```